# Delete one item in an array ReactJS (React Hooks and Redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-reducers

I'm creating a recipe application using MERN stack.

The issue I am stuck on is trying to delete an ingredient found in an array, inside a recipe object. My recipe object looks like this:

[MongoDB Recipe Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PZFa.png)

Each ingredient has a cross next to it that allows you to click on it to remove.

```
<div>
      <ol className='pad5px20px'>
        {addIngredients.ingredients.map(data => (
          <div className='ingredient-item padTB5px' key={data}>
            <li>{data}</li>
            <span onClick={() => removeIngredient(data)}>
              <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
            </span>{' '}
                  
          </div>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
```

The addIngredients and removeIngredient functions look like this:

```
  const addIngredient = e => {
e.preventDefault();

if (query === '') return;

addIngredients.ingredients.push(query);
setIngredients(addIngredients);

setRecipe(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  ingredients: [
    ...prevState.ingredients,
    { id: Date.now(), ingredient: query }
  ]
}));
};

  const removeIngredient = data => {
const results = addIngredients.ingredients.filter(
  e => e.ingredients !== data
);
setIngredients(
  addIngredients.ingredients.filter(e => e.ingredients !== data)
);
};
```

Every time I remove an ingredient from my list I get an error that states "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Is there something that i'm missing here? I have been working on this app for the past couple of months now and I am stuck on this particular bit. I thought a better way would be to use Redux as I have been able to delete a whole recipe using a reducer:

```
    case DELETE_RECIPE:
  return {
    ...state,
    recipes: state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe._id !== action.payload),
    loading: false
  };
```

but how would I be able to target one particular ingredient?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using a mutating function (`push`) in `addIngredients.ingredients.push(query);`.  I'm not sure if that's your problem, but in general in Redux you never want to mutate your objects/arrays.  Instead, you want to make new ones: `addIngredients.ingredients = [...addIngredients.ingredients, query];
`.

Answer (score 1):

I added notes to your code problems)

```
  const addIngredient = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (query === '') return;

     ***STATE MUTATION***
      addIngredients.ingredients.push(query);
     setIngredients(addIngredients);

    setRecipe(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
       ingredients: [
       ...prevState.ingredients,
       { id: Date.now(), ingredient: query }
  ]
}));
};

  const removeIngredient = data => {
    const results = addIngredients.ingredients.filter(
       e => e.ingredients !== data
    );
    ***You're adding ingredients object instead of addIngredients as you used in addIngredient method***
   setIngredients(
     addIngredients.ingredients.filter(e => e.ingredients !== data)
   );
};
```

`addIngredients.ingredients.filter(e => e.ingredients !== data)` returns filtered ingredients instead of addIngredients with filtered ingredients field

How it should be

```
  const addIngredient = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (query === '') return;

     setIngredients({
       ...addIngredients,
       ingredients: [
          ...addIngredients,
          query
       ]
     });

    setRecipe(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
       ingredients: [
       ...prevState.ingredients,
       { id: Date.now(), ingredient: query }
  ]
}));
};

  const removeIngredient = data => {
    const results = addIngredients.ingredients.filter(
       e => e.ingredients !== data
    );

   setIngredients(
    {
       ...addIngredients,
       ingredients: results
  });
};
```